# Display date serial number using TEXT in IF

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I am using an `IF` function to insert a string into a cell if the cell specified is `#N/A`, the function works if I use the following

```
=IF(AS2="#N/A","",CONCATENATE("insert in tempTable values('",AQ2,"','",AR2,"')"))
```

where `AR2` is the date, here are the two different strings I am being returned

```
insert in tempTable values('BIXEN V VASILE ALIN GEORGESCU','19/3/2012')
insert in tempTable values('BANEKIOSKEN V MUHAMMAD NASEEB KHAN','41003')
```

the problem is some of the dates are ok where others are in the date serial number format so I am trying to use the `TEXT` function to change this on the following function it is not working

```
=IF(AS2="#N/A","",CONCATENATE("insert in tempTable values('",AQ2,"','",TEXT(AR2,d/m/yyyy),"')"))
```

i have also tried

```
=IF(AS2="#N/A","",CONCATENATE("insert in tempTable values('",AQ2,"','",IF(AR2=d/m/yyyy,AR2,TEXT(AR2,d/m/yyyy)),"')"))
```

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT: here is the formula working**

```
=IF(AS2="#N/A","",CONCATENATE("insert in tempTable values('",AQ2,"','",IF(AR2="d/m/yyyy",AR2,TEXT(AR2,"d/m/yyyy")),"')"))
```

Comment: Surely AR2 won't ever be equal to "d/m/yyyy" (which is what you are checking - it isn't checking the format). If AR2 is a "date" in text format then TEXT function won't change it. I'd try this version `=IF(ISNA(AS2),NA(),CONCATENATE("insert in tempTable values('",AQ2,"','",TEXT(AR2,"d/m/yyyy"),"')"))` That will also explicitly return #N/A which is "cleaner" than allowing the error, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes around the date format, ie

```
TEXT(AR2,"d/m/yyyy")
```

---

BTW you can use `ISNA(AS2)` rather than `AS2="#N/A"`

Or even (in Excel 2007+)

```
IFERROR(AS2,CONCATENATE( ... ), "")
```

Comment: yes this solved it alright, never spotted that at all, cheers... i know i can use the ISNA() function but that removes the #N/A from the cell then when I actually need the #N/A in the cell so i can remove the lines in notepad++ using these #N/A's

Comment: What I ment was `=IF(ISNA(AS2),"",CONCATENATE( ...`. this has no effect of the source cell `AS2`